# Como puedo poner un gif transparente en una ventana y luego poder moverlo?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

Estoy intentando poner un gif pequeño en una ventana, pero cuando aparece sale la imagen cuadrada y con relleno, cosa que no quería.
la idea es hacer como que se mueve cuando apretas unos botones, o luego de algún comando, pero no sé como hacer para que la imagen sea transparente, ni tampoco como puedo hacerlo para que se mueva, parecido a como se mueven los turtle.
también tenía pensado hacerlo mejor con turtle pero ahí no sé si se puedan poner botones ni poner fondos

Tengo ésto, pero todavia tengo que arreglar la posicion de los botones, y a ustedes no les cargará porque necesitan la imagen

"image" es el fondo
y "cursor" es la imagen que quiero que se mueva

Se pueden convinar los tk con los turtle???

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana=tk.Tk()


image=tk.PhotoImage(file="Sin título-1.gif.gif")
image=image.subsample(1,1)
label=tk.Label(image=image)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)
label.pack()

cursor=tk.PhotoImage(file="ciruclo.gif")
imagen=tk.Label(ventana,image=cursor)
imagen.place(x=100, y=100)


ventana.title("bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)

boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="Elegir",font=("Verdana",15))
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=100,y=380)

boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=100,y=325)

boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=100,y=430)

boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=100,y=377)

boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=100,y=377)



ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comentaré solo los cambios

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
ventana = tk.Tk()
```

hasta acá todo igual, solo que ahora hay que crear las funciones para movimiento, únicamente haré arriba, pero el concepto es básicamente lo mismo para las otras

```
def arriba():
    global posx    #variables de alcance para todo el script no solo la función
    global posy
    global imagen
    
    posx = posx
    posy -= 5 
    canvas.delete(imagen) #*
```

- borra la imagen

  imagen = canvas.create_image(posx,posy, image=cursor) #**

**la dibuja en la nueva posición

Bien para lograr un objetivo aceptable hay que dibujar sobre un contenedor de los controles, mejor que sobre la ventana, para eso se usará:

```
frame = tk.Frame(ventana)
frame.pack()
```

Ahora para dibujar usaremos canvas, más optimizado para este propósito

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=900, height=800)
canvas.pack()

cursor = tk.PhotoImage(file="archivo") # las transparencias son mejores con *png

posx=100
posy=100
```

creamos variables para la posición x e y

```
imagen = canvas.create_image(posx,posy, image=cursor)

ventana.title('bosque')
ventana.resizable(0,0)

boton = tk.Button(text="  ",font=("Verdana",17),command=arriba)

boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
```

es todo prácticamente igual, salvo que agregamos el parámetro command= que es el que se vincula a la función

```
boton.place(x=100,y=325)

ventana.mainloop()
```

y si entendí tu pregunta es eso lo que necesitas para terminar tu código. Como sugerencia, si estás pensando hacer un juego, salvo que es porque quieres aprender y el juego es muy simple, pues bien, adelante, caso contrario no pierdas tiempo, hay otras bibliotecas mejores para ese objetivo, pygame,pgzero,etc.

Comment: Amigo tengo una duda, intenté agregarle el comando abajo poniendo en def parecido a lo que estaba en arriba, pero no me sirvió, me dice "File "C:\Users\leoja\Desktop\laberinto tk con turtle\turtle.py", line 15, in abajo
    posx = posx
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'posx' referenced before assignment"

Comment: ya lo logré, al parecer había que poner los global denuevo jaja, bueno gracias, me sirvió bastante tu ayuda :)